# PyQt5 + Python 3.5.1: QProgressBar seems to not be able to connect to signals

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.5

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot,pyqtSignal

class QutieBar(QProgressBar):
    value = 0

    @pyqtSlot()
    def increaseValue(progressBar):
        progressBar.setValue(progressBar.value)
        progressBar.value = progressBar.value+1

# Create an PyQT4 application object.
a = QApplication(sys.argv)       

# The QWidget widget is the base class of all user interface objects in PyQt4.
w = QWidget()

# Set window size. 
w.resize(320, 240)

# Set window title  
w.setWindowTitle("Progressbar") 

# Create progressBar. 
bar = QutieBar(w)
bar.resize(320,50)    
bar.setValue(0)
bar.move(0,20)

# create timer for progressBar
timer = QTimer()
bar.connect(timer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), bar, SLOT("increaseValue()"))
timer.start(400) 

# Show window
w.show() 

sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Here is the error it's spitting out:

> C:\Users\Pixie\Development\New folder>test6 Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "C:\Users\Pixie\Development\New folder\test6.py",
>   line 38, in 
>       bar.connect(timer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), bar, SLOT("increaseValue()")) AttributeError: 'QutieBar' object has no
>   attribute 'connect'

I have absolutely no idea what is going on. To my extensive searching, this *seems* to be correctly wired up, but for some apparent reason, PyQt5 is being sassy.

Comment: Please include all necessary code & errors in the question itself.

Comment: Using code blocks, see [the syntax help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `bar.connect(timer, SIGNAL("timeout()"), bar, SLOT("increaseValue()"))` which is the old signal-slot syntax from PyQt4.

You should instead use `timer.timeout.connect(bar.increaseValue)` as per [the PyQt5 documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).

Comment: That's it. Thanks.